# Problem in convert jalali date to gregorian

Tags: php, date, jalali-calendar

When enter date 31-06 in jalali year (for example 1397-06-31) to php date function, the output shows one day after that!

```
<?php
$date = date_create('1397-06-31');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
// the output is 1397-07-01
?>
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: PHP doesn't understand jalali dates. You will need to use a package such as https://github.com/morilog/jalali to process them.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't enter a Jalali date, you entered a date ~600 years ago.

June 31st didn't exist that year in your timezone, which is why it skips one day ahead.